# Partial differential equation prime integrals

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, partial-differential-equations

After finding the prime integrals i have to do something more?
For example:
$$ (z-y)^2 \frac {dz}{dx} + xz  \frac {dz}{dy} = xy    $$
The prime integrals are:
$$ C_1 = (z-y)^2+x^2 \text { and } C_2 = y^2-z^2  $$
In other words...
What's the solution of the partial ode after finding the prime integrals?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Normally we write
$$f(c_1)=c_2 \implies y^2-z^2=f((z-y)^2+x^2)$$
$$z^2=y^2-f((z-y)^2+x^2)$$
You don't have Boundary conditions and intitial conditions with the pde ?

Comment: No, i don't have any constraints. The ex says "solve the pde"

Comment: Ok then there is nothing more you can do @PopaStefan I checked your integrals and they are correct.